# Using innerHTML to get a whole page content

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am still a beginner in Javascript and I wondering if I can use innerHTML to post the whole HTML content from another page.
I have used innerHTML to just post an HTML code within the same .js page. For example:

I have **main.js** that contains this

```js
class MyComponent extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
this.innerHTML = `<h1>Hello world</h1>`;
  }
}

customElements.define('my-component', MyComponent);
```

and in the **index.html** I use this code to implement the main.js

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="application/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script> 
</head>
   
<body>
    <my-component></my-component>
</body>
</html>
```

The question is can I include an HTML page instead `<h1>Hello world</h1>` like `header.html` to get the whole HTML code from it? if not, Is there any way to do that?
Thanks.

**Edit:** I mean for example if I have a page named footer.html and in that page, I have an h1 ex. "Hello world" And I need to use the same h1 in another page index.html without rewrite it again. Can I make that h1 as a template to use in any other page using javascript?
My idea that I was looking for is:

- Making main.js
- get h1 from footer.html in main.js
- import that script in index.html
- using h1 in index.html
  I know that I can do that using "include" in PHP but I am just trying to do it by javascript.

Comment: You can use the fetch API

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is unclear. I am not sure what you mean by *post the whole HTML content* Also your example has no reference to "another page". If this page is within the same domain, you should be able to use `.load()` to GET the page. Please clarify. Also you can use `.html()` to get all the HTML elements of a specific element. E.G.: `$(document).html()` would return all the HTML Elements of the Document. Please also supply a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi Twisty, I mean for example if I have a page named footer.html and in that file, I have an h1 ex. "<h1 class="container">Hello world</h1>" And I need to use the same h1 in another page index.html without rewrite it again. Can I make that h1 as a template to use on any other page using javascript?
My idea that I was looking for is:
- Making main.js
- get h1 from footer.html in main.js
- import that script in index.html
- using h1 in index.html
I know that I can do that using "include" in PHP but I am just trying to do it by javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with AJAX. Set an URL for that file and make a get request with AJAX.

Using JQUERY

```
$.get("file_path.html", function(fileText){});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
document.body.innerHTML
```

to access page content.